# Keypress does not work in table with div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have something like this code :

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td id="formulaWidget" class="formula" colspan="3">
                        <div id="formulaEditorContainer" class="FormulaEditor" style="height: 100%;">
                            <div class="head form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                <input type="text" id="UxSearchAddHoc" placeholder="search" class="form-control" style="width: calc(100% - 45px);" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my js code :

```
 $('#UxSearchAddHoc').keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (Number(keycode) === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var a = request.term;
            response = getObjects();
        }
    });
```

keypress does not work in table -> tr -> td -> div . I used tabIndex but didn't work.

I checked document.activeElement and active element : $('#UxSearchAddHoc'). Then I checked focus or not as the following code :

```
$('#UxSearchAddHoc').is(':focus')   //return false
```

I moved my .html to another place and text keypress working but if in table does not work.

Why is this happening ? How can I do for fix ? 
Please..

Comment: Is the content of the table dynamically loaded? If so you'll need to use a delegated event handler

Comment: What do you mean 'event handler' ? How can I do ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: _"keypress does not work in table -> tr -> td -> div"_ it does work. Stick a console log outside the if statement to prove it. Something else must be causing an error, or your logic is faulty.

Comment: @eagle you need to learn what an event handler is.

Comment: @eagle try `$(document).on('keypress', '#UxSearchAddHoc', function(event) {...`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#UxSearchAddHoc').bind("keypress", function (event) {
    
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (Number(keycode) === 13) {
            alert("Enter Key pressed !");
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Other Key pressed !"); 
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td id="formulaWidget" class="formula" colspan="3">
                        <div id="formulaEditorContainer" class="FormulaEditor" style="height: 100%;">
                            <div class="head form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                <input type="text" id="UxSearchAddHoc" placeholder="search" class="form-control" style="width: calc(100% - 45px);" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```